# Вращение тела относительно точки Unity 2d

Tags: unity3d, математика

Каким образом сделать вращение тела относительно заданных dx dy в Unity? Например у меня есть спрайт оружия с рукой, и я смог сделать его вращение относительно своего центра, чтобы оружие смотрело на курсор, как мне вращать не относительно центра спрайта, а относительно заданной точки?

Answer (score 0):

Используй `transform.RotateArround()` вот документация https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html